# Pointers in an array

Tags: c++

Apologies in advance, this is really messy, trial and error + google search haven't helped me untangle it. I have these variable declarations:

```
   std::vector<int> *m_nominal;
   std::vector<int> *m_Tracking1;
   std::vector<int> *m_Tracking2;
   std::vector<int> *m_Tracking3;
   std::vector<int> *m_Tracking4;
```

Which I then put into an array, this declaration is probably where the issues start:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>*,5> array{m_nominal, m_Tracking1, m_Tracking2, m_Tracking3,m_Tracking4};
```

So that in a loop over iSyst they can be filled like:

```
array[iSyst]->push_back(Observables::nTrk(reco_track_jet_central, true, false));
```

This compiles fine, but when running leads to:

```
TUnixSystem::DispatchS... ERROR   segmentation violation
```

Print statements show it's crashing in the push_back loop, if I comment out that array[iSyst] line it compiles and runs.

I have made this run without the seg violation by making them not pointers in the declaration. Then you use `array[iSyst].push_back( ).`

However, I then get output histograms with 'EMPTY' written in them. I looked at variables already declared in the code that do get filled, and they look like:

```
m_NumTrkPt500PV->clear();

  for (const xAOD::Jet* jet : *rjets)
    {
pvLocation = HelperFunctions::getPrimaryVertexLocation(PrimaryVertices);
m_NumTrkPt500PV->push_back(nTrk500(*jet)[pvLocation]);
}
```

The only difference I can see is that the variables where it's working where using pass by reference and I got empty histograms from pass by value. I might've been sent totally in the wrong direction by that logic, maybe it's wrong, but I thought I'd try switching to pointers for the variables I'm trying to add.

I'd appreciate any suggestions of things to try, thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Your best tool for solving this is your debugger. When you step through the program line-by-line and inspect each local variable and function call, do you notice anything strange?

Comment: You are aware that the vector only contains pointers to vectors, and there are no vectors yet, right? Is there a special reason for not simply using proper vectors?

Comment: Have you ever initialized the variables `m_nominal` through `m_Tracking4`? From the code you've shown, they appear to be uninitialized pointers, and thus not useful for anything at all. Why are you using pointers at all?

Comment: How are you initializing your pointers to vector?  Is it with `new std::vector<int>`?  If so, then probably the reason why you're using pointers is because you are used to seeing `new` create objects from other computer languages (Java), and possibly trying to use Java or Java-like techniques in a C++ program?  If that's the reason, pretend Java doesn't exist.

Comment: This question is not answerable without a [mcve], I'm afraid

Comment: I thought it was probably a long shot without a MWE. I think one of those is beyond my abilities, this comes from a huge interlinked set of files which I don't understand well enough. But I'll give it a try, that might help me understand it better! Thanks for reading and for the suggestions anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you intended to write

```
   std::vector<int> *m_nominal = new std::vector<int>;
```

and similarly for the remaining pointers.

Still, this style of programming is just horrible.
Why do you insist on naked pointers and manual memory management?
I guess your code will benefit from something as simple as this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_jet_observables(5);
```

Comment: I can change it to that, but the existing variables in the code (which does seem to work) are all just declared like  ```Float_t m_jetRadius;```
 ```TString m_label;```, do the vector<int>s need a different declaration?

Comment: You've given too little information for me to answer. Once you have a vector (or array) of vectors,  you can easily form a pointer to its elements, e.g. `&my_jet_observables[2]` is a pointer to the 3rd vector of ints. Apart from this, we're not saints who can see your code from a distance. Guessing from variable names, it's High Energy Physics. Look at the code you use and try to stick to the standards used in it. Or ask a local guru.

Comment: The main problem is that your question betrays you're rather  an inexperienced C++ developer. I don't  know if you really know  the difference between stack- and heap-allocated memory, ownership, memory leaks, scopes, RAII and many more. Since the information you share is far form ample, it is impossible to give you a definitively correct advice other than that the pointers you use need initialization. Any detailed advice can be counterproductive or even disastrous.